# Error en método de verificación Cédula C#

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un pequeño problema cuando se verifica la cédula , el cual consiste que me arroja error en las ultimas cédulas emitidas como es el caso de la siguiente **0962492716**, realizando el método de verificación manualmente la cédula concuerda pero en tiempo de ejecución me arroja error , si alguien me podría indicar que problema se esta presentando, adjunto el código y una imagen de como se obtiene

```
 public static bool VerificarCedula(string ced)
    {
        int isNumeric;
        var total = 0;
        const int tamanoLongitudCedula = 10;
        int[] coeficientes = { 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 };
        const int numeroProvincias = 24;
        const int tercerDigito = 6;

        if (int.TryParse(ced, out isNumeric) && ced.Length == tamanoLongitudCedula)
        {
            var provincia = Convert.ToInt32(string.Concat(ced[0], ced[1], string.Empty));
            var digitoTres = Convert.ToInt32(ced[2] + string.Empty);
            if ((provincia > 0 && provincia <= numeroProvincias) && digitoTres < tercerDigito)
            {
                var digitoVerificadorRecibido = Convert.ToInt32(ced[9] + string.Empty);
                for (int k = 0; k < coeficientes.Length; k++)
                {
                    var valor = Convert.ToInt32(coeficientes[k] + string.Empty) *
                    Convert.ToInt32(ced[k] + string.Empty);
                    total = valor > 10 ? total + (valor - 9) : total + valor;
                }
                var digitoVerificadorObtenido = total >= 10 ? (total % 10) != 0 ?
                10 - (total % 10) : (total % 10) : total;
                return digitoVerificadorObtenido == digitoVerificadorRecibido;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

La cédula está formada por los dos primeros dígitos que corresponden a la provincia donde fue expedida, por lo cual los dos primeros números no será mayor a 24 ni menor a 1.
-      El tercer digito es un número menor a 6 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
-      Los siguientes hasta el noveno digito son un número consecutivo.
-      Y el décimo digito es el digito verificador.
Los coeficientes usados para verificar el décimo dígito de la cédula, mediante el algoritmo “Módulo 10”
COEFICIENTES = 2.1.2.1.2.1.2.1.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor describa cual es el error

Comment: El salida de cedula `0962492716` es `False` porque el tercer digito es 6 (y de acuerdo con la regla, debe ser menos de 6). Y hay error en su codigo: cuando comprueba la condicion  `total = valor > 10 ? total + (valor - 9)...`, debe usar el comparacion **>=** como este: `total = valor >= 10 ? ...`

Comment: @Luke efectivamente como indicabas se tenia que realizar ese pequeño cambio y adicional a esto se realiza otra pequeña modificación en la siguiente linea de código en donde se coloca **<=** en la siguiente sentencia `if ((provincia > 0 && provincia <= numeroProvincias) && digitoTres <= tercerDigito)` ya que existía una modificación y a las personas extranjeras que obtiene la cédula de mi país se les asigna como tercer dígito el numero 6, y dejo a continuación el link de donde encontré esta información https://www.jybaro.com/blog/cedula-de-identidad-ecuatoriana/